# Can I display value of a select box using css?

Tags: html, css, tags

A co worker just asked me if I knew of a way to just display the value of a select box option tag insteasd of the the text in between the opening and closing option tag without having to use javascript. I have not found a way how to accomplish this. Is there away to do this?

The sample code is below:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentMain$contentbody$ddlCFDA"     id="ContentMain_contentbody_ddlCFDA" class="wide">
<option value=""> --- Select CFDA --- </option>
<option value="93.003">93.003    Disaster Relief</option>
<option value="93.101">93.101    PPW</option>
<option value="93.102">93.102    RWC</option>
<option value="93.104">93.104    Comp Comm Mntl Hlth Serv (Sed)</option>
<option value="93.109">93.109    Link</option>
<option value="93.119">93.119    Technical Asst Ctr Evaluation</option>
<option value="93.120">93.120    MH Serv For Cuban Entrants</option>
<option value="93.122">93.122    RRCD</option>
<option value="93.125">93.125    MH Planning &amp; Demonstration</option>
<option value="93.128">93.128    MH Statistics Improvement Prog</option>
<option value="93.131">93.131    ATTC</option>
<option value="93.132">93.132    Managed Care (MC)</option>
<option selected="selected" value="93.138">93.138    P&amp;A For Individuals With Mental Illness</option>
<option value="93.144">93.144    High-Risk Youth Population</option>
<option value="93.148">93.148    Demonstration Prog Homeless</option>
<option value="93.150">93.150    PATH</option>
<option value="93.169">93.169    </option>
<option value="93.170">93.170    CYAP</option>
<option value="93.171">93.171    Block Grant</option>
<option value="93.174">93.174    Conference Grants</option>
<option value="93.175">93.175    Wrap Around</option>
<option value="93.179">93.179    SP-SD</option>
<option value="93.194">93.194    Community Partnership Grant</option>
<option value="93.195">93.195    </option>
<option value="93.196">93.196    Target Cities (TC)</option>
<option value="93.216">93.216    HIV/AIDS Demonstration Prog</option>
<option value="93.218">93.218    Subst Abuse Treatment Conference Grants</option>
<option value="93.229">93.229    </option>
<option value="93.230">93.230    KDA</option>
<option value="93.238">93.238    </option>
<option value="93.239">93.239    Policy Research and Evaluation Grants (ASPE)</option>
<option value="93.242">93.242    </option>
<option value="93.243">93.243    Programs of Regional and National Significance</option>
<option value="93.244">93.244    MH Clinical Or Serv Related Tr</option>
<option value="93.274">93.274    Clinical Training Grant/FD</option>
<option value="93.275">93.275    Access to Recovery Grants</option>
<option value="93.276">93.276    ONDCP Drug Free Communities</option>
<option value="93.901">93.901    Communications Coop Agreements</option>
<option value="93.902">93.902    Critical Population (CP)</option>
<option value="93.903">93.903    Criminal Justice (CJN)</option>
<option value="93.911">93.911    Campus</option>
<option value="93.937">93.937    </option>
<option value="93.949">93.949    HIV/AIDS</option>
<option value="93.950">93.950    Capacity Expansion (CP)</option>
<option value="93.958">93.958    CMHS Block Grant</option>
<option value="93.959">93.959    SAPT Block Grant</option>
<option value="93.982">93.982    Disaster Assistance &amp; Emerg</option>
<option value="93.992">93.992    Block Grant</option>

</select>
```

Comment: You'll need to modify the CMS to do this. What CMN are you using?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS.

Comment: No, there's no way to do this with only CSS.

Comment: The only possibility, **in your case**, might be to restrict the width of the select box to only show the first part of the content (which appears to correspond to the value in your case). Although this might be tough cross browser and is very much a work around.

Comment: @w3d Yeah, sort of: http://jsfiddle.net/er2hP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practical terms, it cannot be done in CSS (and it is difficult to see why it *should* be done in CSS if it were possible).

On the theoretical side, you can in principle *add* content after the element content using generated content, e.g.

```
option:after { content: attr(value); }
```

But among popular browsers, Firefox seems to be the only one that supports generated content for the `option` element.

Even more theoretically, you could *replace* the content by using a proposed extension to the generated content mechanism:

```
option { content: attr(value); }
```

But this extension in general (using `content` for real elements, not just `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements) seems to be supported by Opera only, and it does not support it (or generated content at all) for `option` element.

Comment: Regardless of generated content, Firefox seems to be the only browser that supports the `:after` pseudo-element on the `option` element. The `option` element is considered a replaced element and the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) is undefined regarding `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements on replaced elements, so the other browsers are not _wrong_.